# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm getting this from my console when I debug it Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

Here's my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYHERE&sensor=false">
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.249281,-97.81305),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var markerOptions = {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.283288,-97.824286)
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
marker.setMap(map);
```

I fixed the hanging tag, but my map still isn't showing.

Comment: You have added extra `>` in your script tag, <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYHERE&sensor=false">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dangling `>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYHERE&sensor=false">
</script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYHERE&sensor=false"></script>
                              ^ remove the > here
```

Comment: I fixed that, do you have any idea why my map still wouldn't be showing? My CSS looks like this:    #map {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: ok 2 things: 1. Load jquery _before_ the api calls. 2. Create a fiddle if that doesnt fix the issue

Comment: Here is my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=IEMNPtIzr4 and my apologies I'm very new to JS. You have been really helpful.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/yvk76/ Just look hard to see the difference. Couple of minor issues

Comment: Quick question. Would you know if I'm using coda, and I launch a preview into chrome that it would stop this from working?

Comment: It should not. If that is happening, something is not loading properly

Comment: My html is the same as I had above with the correction made. My javascript is how you have yours, as is my css. I'm just unsure of what's not being passed correctly. I'm not even getting a key error so I'd assume my key works.

Comment: One thing i do is, `debugger;` and see if it is hittingthe code.

Comment: Could I provide you screen shots so you have a visual idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You script tag should be like,

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYHERE&sensor=false"> </script>
```